# Compiling Errors

Tags: linux, opengl, fedora, sfml

I'm trying to compile a small game I made with SFML but whenever I do I get this error:

/usr/local/include/SFML/Window/OpenGL.hpp:48:24: fatal error: GL/glu.h: No such file or directory

Naturally, my first thought was I forgot to install opengl libraries, but when I yum install mesa-libGLU, I get this:

Package mesa-libGLU-7.11-0.11.20110525.0.fc15.x86_64 already installed and latest version

So I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a header you're missing, try installing the `-devel` version of that RPM.

```
mesa-libGLU-devel-7.11-0.11.20110525.0.fc15.x86_64
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't notice that haha